# Mysql join tables with or without a condition

Tags: mysql, join

I have a problem i've been having quite a lot recently and it would be great to find a solution for it.
Let's say we have two tables `Table1` and `Table2`. Is there a way to make a `join` on these tables with or without a condition?

e.g:

```
Select * from Table1 t1 left join Table2 t2 on t1.column = t2.column where t2.anothercolumn in (v1,v2,v3) and ...; 

Select * from Table1 t1 left join Table2 t2 on t1.column = t2.column where t2.anothercolumn in ('') and ....;
```

So in these two cases i wanna be able to do a join, if I point a condition on the `t2` column then it would show me results related to that otherwise show everything.

At the moment if I put the `in('')` it wouldn't show anything.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

When you do a `left join`, conditions on the *second* table go in the `ON` clause:

```
Select *
from Table1 t1 left join
     Table2 t2
     on t1.column = t2.column and
        t2.anothercolumn in (v1, v2, v3) and ...;
```

Conditions in the first table go in the `where` clause.  This might seem like an arcane rule.  But if you understand the underlying mechanisms, it makes a lot of sense.

A `left join` keeps all rows in the *first* table, regardless of whether or not the `on` clause evaluates to true.  Hence, a condition on the first table has no effect on the results (because `left join` keeps the first records anyway).

On the other hand, your version turns the `left join` into an `inner join`, because the values on the second table are `NULL` when the `where` clause is processing them.

Comment: did that already, if I put also there in (''), it wouldn't show anything

Comment: I want that if I put a value i get only the records related to that condition and nothing else like an inner join and if I don't i get everything doesn't matter

Answer (score 0):

Your requirements as mentioned call for use of an inner join.
A left join will fetch all records from left table and matching records from the right one. If you want to apply filter on the intersection of two tables, use inner join.

A graphical explanation is available here: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Comment: I know what an inner join is, thank you yet that doesn't solve my issue, if you put empty values in the 'IN' it doesn't show anything

Answer (score 0):

The Process MySQL processing the query is that it first Do From clause that is your left join and then where clause on the column you specify and than the it generate the result set based on the column selected in select clause

(asked)At the moment if I put the in('') it wouldn't show anything.
Reason it would look for the column you specify in where clause and find if it contain '' if yes that result would be displayed if not Zero row

Answer (score 0):

```
Select *
from Table1 t1 left join
     Table2 t2
     on t1.column = t2.column and
     t2.anothercolumn in (coalesce (@input, t2.anothercolumn)) and ...
     where t1.someColumnName is NOT NULL or @value is NULL
;
```

If @input is not null, then all fields will be returned, else filtered fields will be returned.

Comment: Thank for the try, yet this is still not what I want, if I put null in @input it gives everything correct yet if I put a value i'll get the record with the value plus the null ones which is caused by the left join ofc and i just want a specific records with the value

Comment: Any particular reason for not using inner join with this query?

Comment: some of  the records are not mapped so i wanna show them too when there is no input, if I put inner they won't come up

Comment: If you add a conditional where clause,
Select *
from Table1 t1 left join
     Table2 t2
     on t1.column = t2.column and
       t2.anothercolumn in (coalesce (@input, t2.anothercolumn)) and ...;

Comment: where <someColumn> is NOT NULL or @value is null